# what are the implications/demerits if use GET verb for posting/updating the data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

> This question is being asked in the interviews a lot these days.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, I haven't come across this in an interview situation.

Some verbs are said to be Idempotent, that is, they are repeatable and will always return the same result when requested with the same data.  They are non-affecting.  Verbs in this category are Get, Head, Options and Trace.

Non-idempotent verbs include Put, Post, Delete.  These verbs affect data.

From a rest point of view, Get should be idempotent and api consumers will expect that to be the case.  Making it non-idempotent will cause issues for the consumers who don't know that the standard rest setup isn't being followed

Comment: In short, you r trying to say that it will only create confusion to clients.

Comment: Pretty much, if you knew that opening a drawer was supposed to do nothing to the contents, but in fact something fell out without you noticing.  After a while you'd have an empty drawer and no clue as to why, you've only been opening and closing it

Answer (score 0):

The responses from GET are cached by default.

- On the first request the update will happen ok.
- The second request may never reach the server, because the cached response is displayed instead (so no update is performed).

Because of this, people use POST for updates - these are never cached by default.

There is also a limit on the length of URLs in GET requests.

Comment: It makes more sense to me now, why we dont use GET.. Thank you so much.